# CSS override important style - WordPress BETheme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, styling

I currently have a small css problem.

I try to restyle Buttons in a WordPress Theme (BeTheme)

```
<div class="mcb-wrap-inner">
<div class="column mcb_column mcb-item-b2bxp8gm6 one-fifth column_button">
<div class="button_align align_center">
<a class="button btn-home btn-important button_size_2 button_dark" href>
<span class="button_label">My Button</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is this existing css class (output from dev console):

```
.column_button .button {
    margin: 0!important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Does anyone know how to override this !important margin value?

I am happy about your answers :)

Best regards from Germany and stay healthy

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean “override” not overwrite?

Just add your selector to the Additional CSS in theme customization. Don’t forget the `!important`.

```
.column_button .button {
    margin: 10px !important;
}
```

Since the additional CSS is loaded after theme files, it will take precedence over theme CSS.